# Authenticate users from Desktop app to salesforce

Tags: custom, customization, access, component

I have a use case where users have login to salesfroce as well as Desktop app,

I have a Windows desktop application where user logs in and i would like to show one of my custom component inside the WPF application,

i can achieve this using navigate to URL but when user navigates to URL Salesforce asks for login, but i want to authenticate the user as the user logged to WPF app using SSO and even my salesforce is aithenticated using SSO,

how can i by pass this login screen and show the component directly.?

From desktop app c# user wants to navigate to Salesfroce custom component, any suggestions would be of great help .

Answer posted in comment below

Thanks
Arjun.M

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have successfully authenticated the user with SSO (and thus have a valid session `Access Token`) AND your SSO included the **web** scope, you can always start an interactive session by navigating the user to the following URL:

```
$"{SalesforceUrl}/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid={AccessToken}&apv=1&allp=1&display=page"
```

This will bypass the login screens and land you on the default tab of the user.

If you want, you can listen for that navigation and redirect them to where they need to go. Further, you can do this without showing webview to the user so when you do show it, they are where they expect to be.

Lastly, you can make the call to that URL with `HttpClient`, and grab back the `sid` cookie from the SF domain **AND** the documentforce domain, and then attach them to your web view.

Comment: We can achieve this using SSO,

Here is what is did
Enabled SSO in SF
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000329819&type=1

in My WPF App
i have used "wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser" to load my SF page and in my WPF app i did this constructor to persist the cookies
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419483/how-to-save-cookies-in-cefsharp